# DRF - Custom Field Json

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created a custom field in my model for calculating "statistics"

Models.py

```
class Risk(models.Model):
[...]   
def risk_completion(self):
    total = self.controls.count()
    total_completion = self.controls.filter(status="NP").count()

    response_data = {
        'total_controls': total,
        'total_controls_planned': total_completion
    }

    return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

serializers.py

```
class RiskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
[...]
total = serializers.CharField(source='risk_completion')

class Meta:
    model = models.Risk
    fields = (
        [...]
        'total',
    )
```

But DRF returns : `"total": "<JsonResponse status_code=200, \"application/json\">"`

If i'm not using JsonResponse() DRF returns a string : `"total": "{'total_controls': 3, 'total_controls_planned': 2}"`

How can I return "real" Json ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonResponse` is meant to be used as a view reponse, so forget about that.
The second case returns a string because your field is of type charfield, so it "casts" the dictionary your fonction returns to a string.

If you want to keep the structure you can use a [DictField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#dictfield) in place of your charfield.